# Content (sometimes) flashes during Angular routing animation

Tags: angular

I have a simple app in which I'm trying to integrate Angular animations on routing events:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvr1n.jpg

If you see the GIF you will notice that the first 3 route animations are as expected, but with the 4th route animation you see a flicker of the "old" content.

animation.ts

```js
export const slideInAnimation = trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition('watchList => movieDetail', [
    style({ position: 'relative' }),
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ]),
    query(':enter', [style({ right: '-100%', opacity: 0, position: 'fixed' })]),

    group([
      query(':leave', [animate('1s ease-out', style({ right: '100%', opacity: 0 }))]),
      query(':enter', [animate('1s ease-out', style({ right: '0%', opacity: 1, }))])
     ]),
  ]),

  transition('movieDetail => watchList', [
    style({ position: 'relative' }),
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ]),

    query(':enter', [style({ left: '-100%', opacity: 0 })]),
    query(':leave', [style({ position: 'fixed' })]),

    group([
      query(':leave', [animate('1s ease-out', style({ left: '100%', opacity: 0 }))]),
      query(':enter', [animate('1s ease-out', style({ left: '0%', opacity: 1 }))])
     ]),
   ])
]);
```

I'm using `position: 'fixed'` in the queries. This is because when I navigate between routes I preserve the previous scrollTop value:

```js
if (data instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  this.mainContent.scrollTo({
    top: this.scrollService.scrollTopSubject$.getValue()
  })
}
```

So I'm using `position: 'fixed"` on the (red) `movieDetails` route to have that animation in the viewport. Without the `position: 'fixed'` the route animation is placed at the top of the element which could be incorrect depending if the user scrolled.